# Compute differences in the prior experience of employees

Tags: stata

I have the following dataset:

```
clear 
input float(department employee expertise_area share)
  1  56 334     1
  1 143 389   .04
  1 143 334   .18
  1 143 383   .02
  1 143 398    .1
  1 143 414   .02
  1 143 396   .08
  1 143 385   .08
  1 143 403    .3
  1 143 409   .02
  1 143 373   .02
  1 143 392   .06
  1 143 397   .06
  1 143 394   .02
  1 214 373     1
  4 145 399  .029
  4 145 409 .7681
  4 145 311 .0145
  4 145 403 .1884
  4 161  62    .4
  4 161 373    .6
  4 285 355 .5333
  4 285 392 .0333
  4 285 304 .0333
  4 285 310 .2333
  4 285  73 .0333
  4 285 331 .0333
  4 285 399 .0333
  4 285 414 .0667
186 161  62    .4
186 161 373    .6
186 247 409 .0025
186 247 311 .0025
186 247 338   .25
186 247 298 .0051
186 247 334  .649
186 247 337 .0051
186 247 404 .0076
186 247 339 .0051
186 247 301 .0025
186 247 403 .0631
186 247 347 .0025
186 247 336 .0051
186 285 304 .0333
186 285 399 .0333
186 285 355 .5333
186 285 392 .0333
186 285 310 .2333
186 285  73 .0333
186 285 414 .0667
186 285 331 .0333
end
```

I would like to compute the differences between the distribution of the prior experience of employees in a team (or department).

This is the mean Euclidean distance, which calculates that separation of individuals in a team:

[image: formula]

Here, `p_ij` and `p_kj` are the share of employee `i`’s or `k`’s expertise in area `j` over his career and `n` equals the team size.

For example, for department `1`, employee `143`, he has worked `18%` of his career on area `334` (this example corresponds to observation `3`). The team size for department `1` is `3`, that is for department `1`, `n=3`.

In summary, I want to calculate the Euclidean distance for each department `(1, 4, 186)` for 3 points (or employees) each `[(56, 143, 214), (145, 161, 285), (161, 247, 285) respectively]` with `13, 13 and 22` dimensions (or expertise_area) respectively. Note that I should be able to produce output even if a department has more than `3` employees (or points).

The output should look as follows:

```
+------------+--------------------+
| department | euclidean_distance |
+------------+--------------------+
|          1 | .4022              |
|          4 | .4131              |
|        186 | .3882              |
+------------+--------------------+
```

How can I compute this in Stata?

Comment: Can you also show an example of the full calculations by hand for at least one of the departments? That is how you apply the formula to the data? It would help in finding a coding solution.

Comment: Thanks @PearlySpencer. I will post an example of the full calculations by hand for one of the departments.